# How do I attribute a CsvHelper model property to control number parsing?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

This is a property from a model used with CsvHelper.

```
[Name("z")]
public decimal Z {get; set;}
```

The problem occurs while trying to import data. Sometimes the input data for this field takes exponent form like this `0.00E+00` and sometimes it looks like this `280.11`. How can I control parsing? I suspect it involves `NumberStyles` but it is not clear how to use this.

Can I do this with an attribute on the model or am I obliged to create a custom type converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do this, the easiest is probably an attirbute

```
[NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowExponent)]
public decimal Z { get; set; }
```

Or

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.z).TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
    }
}
```

Or if you are really in a pickle you could write your own *TypeConverter*

Comment: What about dependency injecting configuration for mapping, i.e. which property will have which name? If I have a parameterless constructor, than I cannot dependency inject, but if I have IOptions<> parameter, then it states that library cannot find parameterless constructor. Am I using it wrong?