# Unable to convert the scientific notation values to int64 from the CSV file using CSV Helper

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

[image: CSV file having Call_ID column with scientific notation]

I have a csv file having a column "Call_ID" which has a data in scientific notation format (For ex: 3.08E+12). I want to insert those long integers in the form of Int64 into a list. I have a below logic to read and insert into a list

```
                    List<Model> result = null;
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(_excelFileConfiguration.Path + fileName))
                    {
                        var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
                        result = csv.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();
                    }
```

The model class and class map is as follows

```
public class Model
{
  public int AccountId { get; set; }
  public int64 CallId { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<Model>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.AccountId).Name("accountID");
        Map(m => m.CallId).Name("Call_ID");
        Map(m => m.Date).Name("Date");
        
    }
}
```

As of now I'm getting a error **The conversion cannot be performed. Text: '3.08E+12'**

Comment: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1507

Comment: Generally speaking, don't look at CSVs Excel, look at them in Notepad; Excel interprets CSVs and isn't as helpful to us to guide you as actually seeing the raw file contents (which can be pasted as text into the question more easily than as a screenshot, by the way..)

Comment: Moreover, don't open CSVs in Excel and then save them. It looks like Excel has changed the format of CallId in a narrowing operation (conversion of int -> float). Your file are now irreparably damaged.

Comment: the thread https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1507 commented by @canton7 helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: So duplicate of [How do I attribute a CsvHelper model property to control number parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65650386/3744182) then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attribute a CsvHelper model property to control number parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650386/how-do-i-attribute-a-csvhelper-model-property-to-control-number-parsing)